# for loop for lists inside of a list

Tags: python

I'm very new to python. I have a list of lists and need to iterate through them or write a simple for loop (in the below example I have 6 lists in 'data' but I'm not always going to know how many I have so I just need to iterate to the end). I have the python code below

```
data=[['2', '33494.45', '91.415838', '0'], ['2', '33994.3', '101.1738', '0'], ['2','34494.15', '107.04941', '0'], ['2', '34994', '107.67817', '0'], ['2', '35493.85', '107.26302', '0'], ['2', '35500', '107.21114', '0'], ['2', '35993.7', '103.04895', '0']]

self.do_something(data[i])
```

and I need to iterate through such that

```
self.do_something(data[0])
self.do_something(data[1])
self.do_something(data[2])
self.do_something(data[3])
self.do_something(data[4])
self.do_something(data[5])
self.do_something(data[6])
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Basic Python loop](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25228806/basic-python-loop)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just do this:

```
for item in data:
    self.do_something(item)
```

Take a look at the [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/controlflow.html#for-statements).

Answer (score 1):

use:

`map(self.do_something, data)`

Read more about it here:
http://book.pythontips.com/en/latest/map_filter.html

Comment: This doesn't work in Python 3, you need to iterate through the map to evaluate each element of the map with something like `list(map(...))`